# Laravel-5.2 Login give a page not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just installed a fresh copy of laravel 5.2.
inserted the command: php artisan make:auth
gone to the browser, typed : http://localhost/mywebsite/public/login.
and i got this error: The webpage cannot be found.
I am using WAMP.

Edit:
This what it gives on Chrome:

Not Found

The requested URL /mywebsite/public/login was not found on this server.

Route.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('test', function () {
    return  view('index') ;
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Edit 2:

After trying i only can access the first page, but if i try any other route it won't work.All routes return non existent pages.

Comment: Can you explain the error in more detail that would certainly help! Is it a chrome error or a laravel one?

Comment: well actually i haven't tried it on chrome, i only tried it on internet explorer.

Comment: Right, well is the error message from the browser or your laravel application? If it's your browser then you either haven't started wamp or hitting the wrong url.

Comment: from the application.

Comment: Sounds like wamp is running, can you confirm the laravel project is in your www wamp directory? Something like `C:/wamp/www/mywebsite`

Comment: you need to develop your app with virtual host or with localhost:8080 port number indicate directly to your projectname/public ...

Comment: Ok. haakym, yes it's in the www directory.
YLS: i already tried with the virtual host and it's working just fine, however i wanted to work without using the virtual host.
Previous laravel installations worked just fine without the virtaul host for previous laravel versions.

Comment: Okay, so the folder name should correspond to the URL right? So you said the login page doesn't work. If you go to http://localhost/mywebsite/public you should see the index right. If you don't see that then the URL is wrong. If you see the index then try checking the routes are set up properly in `routes.php`

Comment: i can see the index. but the login path doesn't work.Normally it should.

Comment: As I said before,  If you see the index then try checking the routes are set up properly in routes.php

Comment: i have posted the route file. which works fine with homestead virtual host.

Comment: try http://localhost/mywebsite/public/index.php/login if that works then you need to enable your mod_rewrite settings in apache

Comment: Ok, so i tried what you told me Haakym and it worked.Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` in Apache for the default `.htaccess` file to work correctly.